# Reputation score increase not accounted for!

Tags: support

I have edited a number of posts here. I found that whenever reputation decreased by two, it was accounted for, for I checked and found that a post which I edited was deleted.

However, a number of times I have seen it go up by 2. Recently (**this** month), I found my reputation go up from 201 to 203, but nothing in my profile/recent reputation changes accounted for it. If it were, then there should have been a +2 recorded in my reputation history!

Why does this happen?

Comment: Edited 2nd paragraph. The change in rep was quite recent

Comment: I see it... http://i.imgur.com/X5S3tKl.png

Comment: The reputation changed this month! My last edit was on July 18 (see the screenshot you've linked above! The only reason I can think of is that some deleted post was reinstated.